# Stanford Classifier: What are non ngram activeFeatures used to determine scoreOf Datum?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I have number of classifiers to determine whether event descriptions fall into certain categories, i.e. a rock concert, a jazz evening, classical music, etc or not. I have created a servlet which uses the LinearClassifier scoresOf function to return a score for the event description's datum.

In order to look at cases which return unexpected results, I adapted the scoreOf function (public Counter scoresOf(Datum example)) in order to get an array of the individual features and their scores, so I could understand how the final score was arrived at. This works for the most part, i.e. I mostly have lines like:-
1-#-jazz    -0.6317620789568879
1-#-saxo    -0.2449097451977173

as I'd expect. However I also have a couple, which I don't understand:-
CLASS   1.4064007882810108
1-Len-31-Inf    0.4569598446321162

Can anybody please help by explaining what these are and how these scores are determined? (I really thought I was just working on a score built up from the weighted components of my description string).

(I appreciate that "CLASS" & "Len-xx" are set as properties for the classifier, I just don't understand why they then show up as scored elements in their own right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what you want for seeing feature weights, you might also look at LinearClassifier's `justificationOf()`. I think it's the same as what you've been writing....

For the questions:

The CLASS feature acts as a class prior or bias term. It will have a more positive weight to the extent that the class is more common in the data overall. You will get this feature iff you use the `useClassFeature` property. But it's generally a good idea to have it.

The 1-Len feature looks at the length of the String that is column 1.  31-Inf is a length of over 30. This will again have weights as to whether such a length is indicative or not of a particular class. This is employed iff you use the `binnedLengths` feature. This is useful only if there is some general correlation between field length and the target class.

Comment: Apologies for the delay (vacation!) but thank you very much for your reply.

With the data I was testing, I was generally changing the min / max ngram lengths, and size of the training set in order to find optimal precision / recall results. The prop file I was using was set with "binnedLengths=10,20,30", so as per your comments I will comment this out, as there shouldn't really be any correlation at play here.

Re "the class is more common in data overall" please could I ask for some further clarification? I trained and tested on the same number of cases for say "Jazz" events or non Jazz.

Comment: Cont: So I was just wondering if when looking at how common in the data overall, you were meaning False Positives (FPs) being picked up in my non Jazz (identified here as Music) set:-  

Cls Jazz: TP=888 FN=112 FP=39 TN=961; Acc 0.924 P 0.958 R 0.888 F1 0.922  
Cls Music: TP=961 FN=39 FP=112 TN=888; Acc 0.924 P 0.896 R 0.961 F1 0.927  

So here I have many more FPs in my Music class. Is this what gets picked up upon to produce the "CLASS" bias weighting if this has been set?  

Thanks again for your help.